# problem with coloring spherical harmonics

Tags: plotting, special-functions, color

I want to color a spherical harmonics. So I write as follows.

```
color[θ_, φ_] := 
  RGBColor[(Sign[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]]] + 1)/2, 0, 
           (-Sign[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]]] + 1)/2 ];
SphericalPlot3D[ Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]], { θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, φ, r}, color[ θ, φ]]]
```

I expect that the output plot should show the parity of the spherical harmonics with red corresponding to the positive part and blue corresponding to the negative part. But the actual result is all Blue!

[image: spherical harmonic]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` as an option to `SphericalPlot3D`. That should do the trick

```
color[Θ_, Φ_] := 
  RGBColor[(Sign[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, Θ, Φ]]] + 1)/
    2, 0, (-Sign[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, Θ, Φ]]] + 1)/
    2];
SphericalPlot3D[
 Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, Θ, Φ]], {Θ, 
  0, π}, {Φ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, Θ, Φ, r}, color[Θ, Φ]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: hope you don't mind the actual implementation(?)

Comment: Thank you! your solution works. I have an extra question. I somewhat think my code is not so efficient. I was wandering whether **mathematica** will calculate SphericalHarmonic twice, once in the plot body and once in the colorfunction body. Do you have any better way?

Comment: @chris thank you so for the implementation! As per improving the code, the answer by Artes would probably get you started - it is a much more detailed/better answer than mine.

Comment: @user15964 no, the points are calculated first, then the info is passed to the color function, so they're only calculated once.

Comment: @rcollyer Usually yes, but in this case the function `color` calculates the values again (twice).

Comment: In this particular case `ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z,\[Theta],\[Phi],r},If[Sign[x]Sign[z]==1,Blue,Red]]` could be used

Comment: @ssch I missed that.

Comment: @ssch you and rcollyer said differently, but both of you did not give any argument to support your statement. So I am still not sure whether the color function pass the values or not....

Comment: @user15964 The [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) option supplies arguments to the function. In this case the the angles supplied are used in `color` to recalculate the value. I hope that clears it up. Click 'More Information' in the `ColorFunction` docs to see what arguments get sent depending on whith plot command is used.

Answer (score 15):

There are many ways of coloring functions, to visualize spatial dependence of  spherical harmonics one can take advantage of a useful function `Rescale`, so here is a bit different coloring using also imaginary part of the function :

```
col[θ_, φ_] := RGBColor @ Rescale[{  Re @ #, 0, -Im @ #}]& @ SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]
SphericalPlot3D[ Re[ SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]], { θ, 0, Pi}, { φ, 0, 2 Pi},   
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, φ, r}, col[ θ, φ]],
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False ]
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice, +1.

Comment: @gpap Thanks, upvoted your answer too.

Comment: @Artes thank you! But forgive my poor mathematica IQ. I just can't understand the col function, especially the "&@", could you explain it to me ?

Comment: @user15964 `f @ x` means exactly `f[x]` i.e. function `f` acts on the argument `x`. Wherever you find `#` and `&` ( shorthands for `Slot` and `Function` respectively, see  the documentation pages) that means we deal with pure functions, read `tutorial/PureFunctions` in the `VirtualBook`. So here `RGBColor @ Rescale[{  Re @ #, 0, -Im @ #}]& @ SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]` means that `RGBColor` acts on `Rescale` which has arguments, e.g. ` Re @ #` i.e. `Re` acts on something, this `& @ denotes that the function body ends and ˛it acts  on the argument `SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]`.

Comment: @user15964 You should also check `FullForm[RGBColor@Rescale[{Re@#, 0, -Im@#}] &@
  SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, Pi/3, Pi/4]]` and `Trace[RGBColor @ Rescale[{ Re @ #, 0, -Im @ #}]& @ SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ]]`

Comment: @Artes Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Actually I should have understood it without your help. But I forgot there should be a god damn bracket after a & when defining a pure function. This is all my fault.