# Problem with SphericalPlot3D plotting

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the real part of the `SphericalHarmonicY[1,1,θ,φ]`. That is, I want to plot

$$ - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{3}{{2\pi }}} \cos[\phi ]\sin[\theta ]$$

To do so, I evaluated the following expression:

```
SphericalPlot3D[-(1/2) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Cos[φ] Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}]
```

But the result I got doesn't show the negtive part. What is wrong?

[image: spherical]

Comment: What a negative part do you expect ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/problem-with-coloring-spherical-harmonics

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is about colouring the plot; this one is about parts of the desired plot not showing up at all. Unless there's some subtle property of Mathematica I'm missing that makes these the same thing, which, given that Mathematica is sufficiently complicated, is a possibility I won't dismiss...

Comment: @Rahul Someone flagged this post to be closed but didn't post that link.  I chose not to close the question myself, but I put the link there for others to decide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The negative part is plotted with negative radius, so it's at the opposite position of where you expect it -- it's exactly overlapping the positive part. You'll have to plot its absolute value or its square, as Nasser suggests, and indicate its negativeness using a different colour or something. Here's one way to do it:

```
f[θ_, φ_] := -(1/2) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Cos[φ] Sin[θ]
pos[x_] := If[x >= 0, x, Null]
SphericalPlot3D[{pos[f[θ, φ]], pos[-f[θ, φ]]},
 {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Lighter@Lighter@Red, Lighter@Lighter@Blue}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to replace the escaped characters with their Unicode equivalents? I searched on meta but only found [rcollyer saying they *would* do this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/875/484), but not *how* to do so.

Comment: Oh well, I pasted them in from Character Map. Hope I didn't make a mistake somewhere.

Comment: you can type $\phi$ within the editor and then cut an paste the rendered version.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the concern about rendered chars. I hate having to read `\[WhateverCharYouWant]`

Comment: @chris: Unless the editor is different from the notebook interface, that doesn't work for me. Whether it's an input or output cell, whenever I copy a `θ` it pastes as `\[Theta]` outside Mathematica.

Comment: you need to type $\theta$ in the StackExchange page.

Comment: @chris: Oh, that. Yeah, that makes sense. Silly me.

Comment: @RahulNarain Have you seen this: [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/245)

Comment: negative part is plotted with negative radius, that is the key. why didn't I realize it before? Thank you very much!

Comment: Honestly, I use the $\LaTeX$ interpreter on the site itself. I will input what I need in the edit window, and then copy from the display view below it. It seems to be the simplest method.