# How to graph a 3D function of two variables?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to graph this:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
x(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\cos(t) &&\cos(s), \\
y(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\sin(t) &&\cos(s), \\
z(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\sin(s) &&
\end{alignat*}

The following is: $m = 4$, $n = 1$, and $k = 8$:

[image: A three-dimensional rose with eight lobes]

The underlying idea is to take $\rho = \cos(m\theta)\cos^{k}(n\phi)$ in spherical coordinates
$$
(x, y, z) = (\rho\cos\theta \cos\phi, \rho\sin\theta \cos\phi, \rho\sin\phi).
$$

[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209858/what-equation-will-create-a-3d-rose-curve)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to use Wolfram|Alpha are explicitly [off topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Stink, I will just remove the WOlfram Alpha part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with coloring spherical harmonics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/problem-with-coloring-spherical-harmonics)

Comment: vote to re-open?

Comment: But have you looked up `SphericalPlot3D[]` in the docs?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, Here is what happened: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823860/how-to-graph-3d-functions-of-two-variables-on-wolfram-alpha

Answer (score 6):

```
{a, m, n, k} = {1, 4, 1, 8};

ParametricPlot3D[a Cos[m t] Cos[n s]^k Cos[s] { Cos[t], Sin[t], Sin[s]/Cos[s]}, 
    {s, -Pi, Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively,

```
x[s_, t_] := a Cos[m t] Cos[n s]^k Cos[t] Cos[s];
y[s_, t_] := a Cos[m t] Cos[n s]^k Sin[t] Cos[s];
z[s_, t_] := a Cos[m t] Cos[n s]^k Sin[s];
ParametricPlot3D[{x[s, t], y[s, t], z[s, t]}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, {t, -Pi, 
  Pi}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> 40]
(* ==> same picture *)
```