# Problem with plotting spherical harmonics

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I am new to Mathematica, trying to plotting spherical harmonics of a wave functon. I want to plot
[${}Y^0_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics). So I typed

```
SphericalPlot3D[5 Cos^3[θ] - 3 Cos[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

It gives me an empty plot like this:

[image: Picture]

When I copy the same equation

```
(5 Cos^3[θ] - 3 Cos[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi})
```

into Wolfram|Alpha, it gives me a 3d plot looks like "waves"(sorry, I couldn't put the picture because my reputaion is less than 10)

My main question is What's wrong with my input in Mathematica?

Comment: I think the constant in the front of the equation is not important for spatial plot. So I didn't write it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with coloring spherical harmonics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/problem-with-coloring-spherical-harmonics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong is that `Cos^3` is not a function. The following works:

```
SphericalPlot3D[5 Cos[theta]^3 - 3 Cos[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: plot]

To debug your issue, you could have tried to plot `5 Cos^3[theta] - 3 Cos[theta]` for example and see that it gives an empty plot. Then plot `3 Cos[theta]`, etc. until you understand what's wrong.

Comment: I try it with ${}Y^1_3$ SphericalPlot3D[
 E^(I$\phi$) Sin[$\theta$]] (5 Cos[$\theta$]^2 - 1), {$\theta$, 0, 
  Pi}, {$\phi$, 0, 2 Pi}] It still empty. What's wrong?

Comment: `E^(I*phi)` is complex-valued. What output would you expect?

Comment: may be it's a physics problem, It should be the Atomic d orbital. I misunderstood the physics process.

Comment: @Chao, shouldn't you be plotting the real part, the imaginary part, or the absolute value?

Comment: @ChaoSong Maybe relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Real_form

Comment: @J.M. May be I don't understand the equation. I will try real and imaginary separately。

Comment: @J.M. Thank you!